# Почему не выделяется первый вариант в Intellisense?

Tags: c#, intellisense

Пишу например название класса, мне Intellisense подсказывает правильный класс, но он не выделяется в подсказке, а соотвественно я не могу просто нажать Enter, чтобы название класса вставилось, приходится нажимать клавишу вниз, чтобы выделить класс и тогда Enter. Раньше все работало, как вернуть?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, наверно, имеет смысл написать ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поведение завершения подсказки меняется в меню: Edit > IntelliSense > Toggle Completion Mode. Или просто нажать шорткат Ctrl+Alt+Space.

Примечание: в том режиме, который включен у вас сейчас, можно нажимать клавишу TAB для автодополнения.